# Rest - QueryParam getting null values

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, query-string

I have the following method:

```
@Path("/criar_evento")
@GET
@Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public synchronized Evento addEvento(@QueryParam("nome") String nome, @QueryParam("data") String data, @QueryParam("tipo") String tipo) {
    Evento evento = new Evento(nome,data,tipo);
    System.out.println(nome + "\n" + data + "\n" + tipo);
    return evento;
}
```

When I try to run this terminal code:

```
curl http://localhost:8001/sd/evento/criar_evento?nome=teste&data=25082001&tipo=basket
```

I get the data and tipo as null values but not the name

Here is the output on the server:

```
teste
null
null
```

But if I try for example:

```
curl http://localhost:8001/sd/evento/criar_evento?data=25082001&tipo=basket&nome=teste
```

In the server I get:

```
null
25082001
null
```

Any ideas in how to fix this?

Comment: When I use the link in the browser all works just fine

Comment: Not an expert, but try without `@Consumes`.  The `GET` method handles only key-value pairs in the URL, and `@Consumes` may be confusing the code (`@Confuses`?)

Comment: `&` may be being interpreted by your shell. Try enclsing your URL in `'` characters.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the "@Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})" this means that the addEvent method is expecting an Input Json object and you are sending values separated by commas in the tests.

you should send a json object like this:

```
{
'name'='test',
'data'='25082001',
'type'='basketball'
}
```

and you should test through postman.